# Syantax Error in a JavaScript login Controller file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, google-signin

I am trying to deploy the Litefarm open source project. I have first deployed it on Windows and it's working, but now I have to deploy it on Linux. I am trying on Ubuntu 20.04, but I am getting some syntax errors in the "loginwithgoogle" function although the same code was working perfectly on Windows.

The function:

[image: The function picture]

Ubuntu terminal:

[image: Ubuntu terminal image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the "How do I ask a good question" article before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask To be able to help you, we would need the section of code that is bothering you, in text form (not in a screenshot), and the full error message you are receiving. You can edit your question to provide more useful information. That said, from your screenshot, I see you are using an older version of JavaScript that doesn't support the `?.` operator.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your are running a NodeJS version on Linux that it doesn't support conditional chaining.

See your node version doing on the command line:
`node --version`

Optional chaining is currently not supported in Node.js version 13 and below.